# File identified but cannot be deleted - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, delete-file

So I'm trying to make the a program that deletes files which can be launched from the command lines. But when I run it, it fails and returns the following message: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'test.txt'. Here's the code:

```
    import sys
    import os
    num = int(sys.argv[1])
    files = os.listdir(sys.argv[2])
    for file in files[:num]:
        print('Deleting '+file+'...')
        os.remove(file)
```

The file is identified but it cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the directory path back to the path:

```py
import sys
import os
num = int(sys.argv[1])
files = os.listdir(sys.argv[2])
for file in files[:num]:
    print('Deleting '+file+'...')
    os.remove(os.path.join(sys.argv[2], file))
```

`os.listdir` will only return the basename of the file, whereas you'll need a relative or full path